# log4net - event viewer appender not working

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

I checked:

[log4net with EventLogAppender doesn't log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088226/log4net-with-eventlogappender-doesnt-log)

and tried to do almost the same as the answer in that question, but without success, and also I'm running Visual Studio as an admin.

.config file looks like this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>

    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2"/>
  </startup>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.Patternlayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level %logger - %message%newline "/>
      </layout>
      <!--<level value="ALL"/>-->
      <threshhold value="ALL"></threshhold>
      <!--<param name="Threshold" value="ERROR" />-->
      <!--<logName value="Services"/>-->
      <applicationName value="SikuliTestResultImporter"/>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL"/>
      <appender-ref ref="EventLogAppender"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

And I try to do something like this:

```
private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("EventLogAppender");

try
{
    throw new Exception("Exception mon!");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    log.Error(ex.Message);
}
```

I'm using log4net assembly for .NET 2, if that has to do with anything.

I just get the error that the .config is not a valid xml file:

> log4net:ERROR Exception while reading ConfigurationSettings. Check
>   your .config file is well formed XML.

Comment: Diagnostics: Please add the following lines to your web.config, then run (debug) and see the output window, and solve or get back here with the extended diagnostic info. Good luck. (sorry for the messy code, but this is a _comment_) : <appSettings>
    <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true" />
</appSettings>

Comment: and... Do you have a configSection like this? (Your code from you config file does not shows that) :  <section name="log4net" type="....

Comment: No, I don't. Can you please provide more info on what I'm missing in the config file?

Comment: (not related with the issue but...) The parameter of GetLogger is _not_ about the logger name, instead it will identify the code part where the log is coming from (free string) typically you class name.

Comment: Please see the Q/A what you were referring to (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088226/log4net-with-eventlogappender-doesnt-log). There is a part you are missing: <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
  </configSections>

Comment: Post your whole config file it also seems you are making some mistake when copy and pasting and/or editing it.

Comment: configSections, if there,  should be the first entry in your config file. Move it above the startup section.

Comment: If you enable catching CLR exceptions, the inner exception will clearly point out this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: (the configSections goes first, unless you got the exception you described)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <startup>
       <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2"/>
  </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.Patternlayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level %logger - %message%newline "/>
      </layout>
      <!--<level value="ALL"/>-->
      <threshhold value="ALL"></threshhold>
      <!--<param name="Threshold" value="ERROR" />-->
      <!--<logName value="Services"/>-->
      <applicationName value="SikuliTestResultImporter"/>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL"/>
      <appender-ref ref="EventLogAppender"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: OK, next time I will try :-)